# What is the difference between Logistic Regression and Single Neuron Perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, perceptron

Both seem to do the same thing, wanted to know if there is any difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

If the single neuron perceptron has a sigmoid activation function, then there is no difference.

In fact, I think Andrew Ng gives logistic regression as his first example of a neural network in [his coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning?specialization=deep-learning).

Comment: That's true, Andrew Ng spent part of week 2 of the course "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" (the first course of the Coursera Deep Learning Specialization) to show that logistic regression is an elementary neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take the Training and the Prediction aspects of Logistic Regression and Single Neuron Perceptron to understand where they are the same and where they are different.

**Training**

- Logistic Regression: It minimizes the log-loss
- Single Neuron Perceptron: It can minimize either log-loss or hinge loss. The
  architecture of Single Neuron Perceptron provides the flexibility
  needed to change the loss function, provided it is differentiable.

**Prediction**

Let w be the weight, x be the input, b be the bias, and y be the output in a binary classification i.e., y ϵ {0, 1} classes

Logistic Regression: It has the following 3 operations:

1. Summation of Products: wᵀx + b
2. Sigmoid function: σ(wᵀx + b)
3. Threshold value (τ): If σ(wᵀx + b) >= τ, then  y ϵ 1 else if σ(wᵀx +
   b) < τ then y ϵ 0

Single Neuron Perceptron: It has the following 2 operations:

1. Summation of Products: wᵀx + b
2. Activation function

Case 1: If Activation function is Threshold function, then if (wᵀx + b) >= τ then y ϵ 1 else if (wᵀx + b) < τ then y ϵ 0

Case 2: If Activation function is a sigmoid function (σ)

In this case, the output will be a value between 0 & 1, which cannot be directly used for classification.
The sigmoid output has to be used along with a Threshold value τ, to classify it to a class 0 or 1, i.e.,

If σ(wᵀx + b) >= τ, then  y ϵ 1 else if σ(wᵀx + b) < τ then y ϵ 0.

This modification has to be done to the Single Neuron Perceptron architecture to make it behave exactly like the Logistic Regression.

These are the main differences and similarities between Logistic Regression and Single Neuron Perceptron.